# Make div 50% width of its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been looking around google/forums and havent really found an answer to this. I am wondering if I can, in CSS, size a div to 50% width of its contents. I see that calc() doesnt work with auto, but basically what I want to accomplish is width: calc(auto/2). Can I do this in CSS, or does it have to be done after the page is loaded in javascript/jquery?

Note:the height will be 100% with an image in it so I wont want to use px values.

Comment: you can't really resize a div according to the size of it's children, but it is easy to do the reverse. I think I would need a jsFiddle from you first.

Comment: since children take the shape of their parents, how can you even tell how big the child is to cut it by half?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your internal content is just the image, maybe something like this:

```
var innerwidth = $('.parentdiv').children('img').width();
$('.parentdiv').css('width', innerwidth);
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but I don't see why this wouldn't work. Hope it helps :)

Edit: I am agreeing with what the comments said - there really isn't a way to use CSS to figure out the size of a child.

Comment: that should work and I will probably end up with something like that. In my case it would be innerwidth/2, but thats really neither here nor there as to whether your code would work. My main question was whether this could be accomplished in css which it appears is not possible.

Comment: Correct - CSS is only capable of looking forward and downward in the DOM tree, not upward or backward. All you can do is set the child element to 50% of its own width, and have the parent wrap around that, or set the child element to 200% of its parent.